# EditContext.IsModified() is false for programmatically set properties

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

If the user changes a field, then want to automatically fill some other fields. I got this example working:

```
<EditForm @ref="form" Model="m">
    <InputText Value="@m.Field1" ValueExpression="@(() => m.Field1)"
        TValue="string" ValueChanged="@(value => Field1Changed(value))" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="m.Field2" />
    <InputText @bind-Value="m.Field3" />
    <button @onclick="Check">check</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    class MyClass
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public string Field3 { get; set; }
    }

    MyClass m { get; set; } = new();
    EditForm form;

    async Task Field1Changed(string value)
    {
        m.Field1 = value;

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); // simulate lookup
        m.Field2 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    void Check()
    {
        FieldIdentifier field2Id = form.EditContext.Field(nameof(m.Field2));
        bool isModified = form.EditContext.IsModified(field2Id); // false

        m.Field3 = isModified.ToString();
    }
}
```

If Field1 is changed, then Field2 is set in response.

The problem is that only the field that the user changed, is being marked as modified. Other fields, don't get marked with the CSS class `modified`.

I'm using the button and `Field3`, to show whether the `EditContext` has marked `Field2` as modified.

I'm new to Blazor, so this is probably a fundamental misunderstand from me.

**What's wrong with my code and how do I get what I want?**

Comment: There's a flaw in the way edit context tracks modified/unmodified.  It thinks a field is modified if it's changed from the last entered value, not the original value.  I can provide a hack that will give you the modified class, or I can show you how to track object state properly and thus modified/unmodified against the original record values.   The second is somewhat more code.  Which would you like?

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis  it's hard to judge since i have very little idea. properly tracking the object state sounds better. is it easily reusable for different forms? i think i would like the code for properly tracking

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis i would like to see your solution for properly tracking object state, regardless of whether it is reusable for different forms. sorry for my late response earlier

Comment: NP.  See this Github Repo.  - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.EditContext.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem would be notifying the EditContext that some fields have changed programtically in the following way:

```
_editForm.EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(_editForm.EditContext.Field("PropertyName")));
```

Be sure to put in the actual name of the property that has programatically been changed instead of "PropertyName"